# "Failed to download repository" Ubuntu 17.10 Need help!

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, repository

Just signed up, I need help. When I try to upgrade to the newest version of Ubuntu I get an error saying "Check your Internet Connection", I than disconnect/reconnect so many times and still get the same problem. I sent so much time trying to figure this out, would be awesome if someone could help me.

Error: `E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/programs-ppa/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.`

Please reply telling me how to give you more information so you can help me?
I've switched to Xorg and switched back and I'm still getting the same error.
I've had this problem for the last few weeks, I've given up so I am here asking the community for help.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm trying to upgrade to the newest version of Ubuntu without losing my Files on ubuntu. Thanks in advance to the people who attempt to help me!

Comment: The PPA you are trying to use does not support Ubuntu 17.10 - see similar question here: [Xenial repository does not have a Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/xenial-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)